# wordpress sharding: which multi-db plugin to use?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, sharding

I've got a wordpress multisite installation that's hosting enough blogs I need to shard the database. I see there are three plugins available to spread wordpress across multiple databases:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hyperdb/
- http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-db
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shardb/

I'm trying to decide which one to use, but I haven't really found much info comparing them[1].

Does anyone have experience deploying any of these three tools? Or better yet, experience with more than one of them and a rundown of why you switched.

Thanks,
Bethany

[1] http://mu.wordpress.org/forums/topic/16244

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the wordpress action is over here on this nice wordpress stackechange site, check it out:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

And here's an answer to this question, over there.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/wordpress-sharding-which-multi-db-plugin-to-use